# MYSQL group by time for non calendar day over a day

Tags: mysql

I want to be able to group some sales to get totals but a day is based on 18:00:00 the night before to 17:59:59.

The issue is that the time is just hh:mm:ss in its own column and date is in its own, so the solutions I have found won't work as both columns need to be as one.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `exported` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `acc` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `card` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `transdate` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `product` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `qty` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
  `total_incl` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `realdate` date NOT NULL,
)
```

This is the query I want to use to get what I want but I want it based on time 18:00:00 on one realdate to 17:59:59 the next. I don't have access to change the table structure.

```
SELECT SUM(  `total_incl` ) , LEFT(  `product` , 1 ) AS product,  `realdate` 
FROM  `tbl_opttrans` 
WHERE  `acc` =  ''
GROUP BY LEFT(  `product` , 1 ) ,  `realdate`
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract 6 hours from the date for aggregation purposes:

```
SELECT SUM(`total_incl`) , LEFT(`product`, 1) AS product, 
       (case when time >= '18:00:00' then date_add(realdate, interval 1 day)
             else realdate
        end) as realdate
FROM  `tbl_opttrans` 
WHERE  `acc` =  ''
GROUP BY LEFT(`product`, 1),
         (case when time >= '18:00:00' then date_add(realdate, interval 1 day)
               else realdate
          end)
```

Comment: But since realdate is yyy-mm-dd without time in it that won't be correct as it needs to take into account time.

Comment: @CHinAU . . . There was some sort of wishful coding on my part -- the original version could not have worked (if `realdate` had a time component, it needed to convert the value to a date).  In any case, your question is clear that `time` is in a separate column.  You just need a `case` statement.